# Can the elementary os loki clock display seconds?

Tags: release-loki

I would like the elementary os loki lock-screen clock and the wingpanel clock to show seconds. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

No, right now it is not possible to display seconds.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel-indicator-datetime/pull/53) there seems to be a pull request ready to be added to the codebase. I don't know what's left for this to be included in next release. Hope this helps